# Trying to get property 'first_name' of non-object

Tags: laravel

I am trying to fetch digitizing order related to the user but unfortunately, I am facing an error.

Please see this error: https://flareapp.io/share/VmeWJ47Q

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
  $data=
     [
       'digitizings'=>Digitizing::with('user')->paginate(8)
     ];
  return view('front_end.profile.digitizing.digitizing_view_order',$data);
}
```

**User Model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   use Notifiable;
   public function digitizing()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Digitizing','user_id');
   }
                       
}
```

**Digitizing Model**

```
class Digitizing extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['id','order_name','height','width','urgent','image',
  'order_placement','required_format','order_fabric','instruction','user_id'];

protected $table ="digitizing_orders";

 public function user()
 {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
 }
}
```

**HTML view**

```
 @foreach($digitizings as  $key =>$digitizing)
    <tr>
        <td>DPO# {{$digitizing->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$digitizing->created_at}}</td>
        <td>{{$digitizing->order_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$digitizing->user->first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$digitizing->user->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$digitizing->released_date ??  'processing'}}</td>
        <td><a href="">View</a>  
        </td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does every Digitizing-Entry has set a valid `user_id` in database? Try checking eager loaded data is set before accessing it.

Comment: Yes Digitizing-Entry has set a valid user_id in database

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow @thommis-fehremann! your answer is not really an answer but more a question, it should be a comment on the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the data to the view like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $digitizings = Digitizing::with('user')->paginate(8);  
    return view('front_end.profile.digitizing.digitizing_view_order',$digitizings);
}
```

Comment: return $data   please check it user is giving null https://ibb.co/H7WHtqB

Comment: The result in your link had one user record right at the bottom, so i'm assuming that some records are not loading correctly duo to an issue in your Models relationships try to manually define foreign keys and double check on the records in the database.